# Swiping to the next Fragment with a button click

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Here is my code:

**FirstView.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstView extends Fragment
{
    private TextView firstText;
    private Button btn;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1,container,false);


        firstText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneText);
        btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.viewOneBtn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonEvent());
        return view;

    }

    private class ButtonEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new SecondView();

        }

    }
}
```

**SecondView.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondView extends Fragment
{
    private TextView secondText;
    private Button secondViewBtn;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view2,container,false);


        secondText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.secondViewText);
        secondViewBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.secondViewBtn);

        secondViewBtn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonEvent());
        return view;

    }

    private class ButtonEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            secondText.setText("Second View Text changed");

        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity  {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyAdapter pageAdapter;
    private static final int ITEMS = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pageAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position==0)
            {
                return new FirstView();
            }
            else
            {
                return new SecondView();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this code, when I click on the `Button` in FirstView, I need to move to the SecondView. I tried with `Intents` but guess it is wrong. Currently this is having the Swipe function because of the `ViewPager`, I need to this to move to the SecondView when the button is clicked, with the same swipe functionality.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just add a new method that moves fragments to your activity:

```
public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}
```

and call it from a button listener:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setCurrentItem (1, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This method comes to the 'Activity' or 'Fragment' ?. I mean 'MainActivity.java' or 'FirstView.java' ?

Comment: The first one goes to the main activity and the second goes to the fragment onclick listener.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, Thank you :)

Comment: Is there any way to put setCurrentItem method to put in parent fragment which will contain viewpager?

Answer (score 4):

you can define in your activity the below functions:

```
public void next_fragment(View view) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
}

public void previous_fragment(View view) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
}
```

then call them from your layout as:

```
android:onClick="next_fragment" for the "NEXT" button
```

and

```
android:onClick="previous_fragment" for the "PREVIOUS" button
```